# Multiple index files in different folders?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just figured out that if I have multiple folders in my website such as logout and login I can then have a log out/in page within the folders called index.php
Now when someone goes to project.com/login/ it will load up the index.php file in that folder and the url will look nice.

Is there any problem in doing this?

Comment: u don't need multiple folders, u just need url rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Candy Pointed out it is better to do this with url rewrite rather heeps of folders and index files. I went and looked it up and you can do a lot of cool things.

for the basics:

1. http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/
2. http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html

Instead of creating many folders which would make the site confusing (for the developer) and having numerous index.php files which would also get confusing if you were editing more than one at a time, you can use the apache mod_rewrite module which lets you transparently (the url in the address bar stays the same) redirect one URL to another. You could use this to clean up messy url's and have `/login/` instead of `/login/login.php` or `/user/1335591/` or even `/user/'username'/` rather than an ugly url which is hard to remember like the following: `/user/user.php?user=1335591`

1. to start first put `RewriteEngine on` in your .htaccess file to turn it on
2. redirects are then written in the .htaccess file in sequence

**Below is an example:**

1. `RewriteRule ^products/([0-9][0-9])$ /products/$1/ [R]`
2. `RewriteRule ^products/([0-9][0-9])/$ /productinfo.php?prodID=$1`

If the user types in `products/12` the first rule will append a trailing slash to it. The second rule will transparently redirect this URL to `productinfo.php?prodID=12`